# Loading an ArrayList from another serialized class to use in a ListView

Tags: java, android

I am still new to Android, I'm primarily an iOS developer.

I don't know why I can't test to see whether or not the ListArray is empty or not. I need to test and use the size of it anyways.

This is declared within the class:
     Projects projects = new Projects();

The following code does not like projects.videos.size() being compared nil or 0.

```
try
{

if (projects != null)
{
int numberOfVideos = projects.videos.size();
    if(numberOfVideos==0)
    {
//           myStringArray = new String[projects.videos.size()];
//          
//          
//          
//          for (int i = 0;i < projects.videos.size();i++)
//          {
//              myStringArray[i] = projects.videos.get(i);
//          }
    }   
    else
    {
//          myStringArray = new String[1];
//          myStringArray[0] = "No projects";
    }
}
else
{
    System.out.println("Sucess");
}

}

catch (Exception e)
{
System.out.println(e);
System.out.println("somethingbad has happened");
System.out.println(projects.videos.size());
}
```

This is what the projects class looks like:

```
 package com.example.musicvideomaker;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.UUID;
import java.io.Serializable;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class Projects implements Serializable{

public String projectName;
public String musicStuff;
public String songTitle;
public String guid;
public boolean isBuiltVideo;
public boolean isListOfBuiltVideos;
public int selectedIndex;

public ArrayList<String> videos;
public ArrayList<String> builtVideos;
public ArrayList<Number> tPoints;

public void setProjectName(String projectName)
{
    this.projectName = projectName;
}

public void setMusicStuff(String musicStuff)
{
    this.musicStuff = musicStuff;
}

public void setSongTitle(String songTitle)
{
    this.songTitle = songTitle;
}

public void setGuid()
{
    UUID uuid = UUID.randomUUID();
    this.guid = uuid.toString();
}

public void isBuiltVideo(boolean isBuiltVideo)
{
    this.isBuiltVideo = isBuiltVideo;
}

public void isListOfBuiltVideos(boolean isListOfBuiltVideos)
{
    this.isListOfBuiltVideos = isListOfBuiltVideos;
}

public void setSelectedIndex(int selectedIndex)
{
    this.selectedIndex = selectedIndex;
}

public void addRecordedVideo(String recordedVideo)
{
    this.videos.add(recordedVideo);
}

public void addBuiltVideo(String builtVideo)
{
    this.builtVideos.add(builtVideo);
}

public void addTPoint(Number tPoint)
{
    this.tPoints.add(tPoint);
}


}
```

Comment: What do you mean it doesn't like it? What happens/doesn't happen?

Comment: Have you checked of projects.videos == null?

Comment: It still crashes when I check for videos being null or projects.videos.size()==null  is wrong syntax.

Comment: What is the actual error that you get?

Comment: Ok so projects.videos==null   works.  For some reason it crashes when I try int numberOfVideos = projects.videos.size();  I looked at the documentation and .size()  is an integer, so I don't know why that didn't work. Maybe because projects was null.            http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html

Comment: If it was `null` then yes that would crash when you try to call `size()` on it.

Answer (score 0):

I removed int numberOfVideos = projects.videos.size();

Instead of using if(numberOfVideos==0) I used projects.videos == null

I think it was because my projects are null so it crashes when trying to pull the size of the arrayList.